# PHP mail function prepends x-msg to all links...?

Tags: php, email

The mail go through fine but the links look like this: **x-msg://63/'www.something.com/'**

```
$from_user = $_POST["fromuser"];
$subject = $_POST["subject"];

$headers = "From: $from_user <{$_POST['fromemail']}>\r\n". 
               "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n" . 
               "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n" .  "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

     if(mail($_POST["toemail"], $_POST["subject"], wordwrap(urldecode($_POST["ebody"]),70), $headers)){
     ...
     }
```

Is it server-related?

The code of the body:

```
$this->ebody = "<html><head><title>" . $this->subject . "</title></head><body>
<img src='$imageurl' height='65px'><p><strong>AUTOMATED ORDER FORM.</strong>

</p>Please do not reply this message.<p>" . $body . "</p><hr>All Rights Reserved.<br><a href='http://www.something.com'>Company Name.</a></body></html>";
```

The resulting email (raw source):

```
> To: ###@gmail.com Subject: New Order - 14/06/12 MIME-Version: 1.0
> Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8 X-Priority: 3 X-Mailer:
> PHP5.2.9 From: KSONE <noreply.ksone@something.com> Reply-To: Sales
> <sales@something.com>
> 
> 
> <html><head><title></title></head><body><img
> src=\"http://www.something.com/imgs/logo.png\"
> height=\'65px\'><p><strong>AUTOMATED VENDOR ORDER
> FORM.</strong></p>Please do not reply this message 027777777<p>Hello
> World!</p><hr>1/76 All Rights Reserved 12120.<br><a
> href=\'http://www.something.com\'>Company Co., Ltd.</a></body></html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved: It was because of something I left out in the question. I created an API on a remote mail-enabled server, which a local script make a POST request via CURLs. Thought the CURLs request went through fine, the output email are incorrectly escaped. This is because I did not do a urlencode on my POST variable causing crazy things to happen.

Answer (score 9):

AFAIK `x-msg://` is the placeholder scheme that Mail.app prepends to all links that do not have a valid scheme. In other words, your links probably look like `://foo/bar` or something similar, in which case Mail.app inserts `x-msg` to make a complete, valid URI.

Fix the links in your app to send full, valid URLs.

Comment: @40Plot `something.com` is not a valid **URL**. It's only a valid *domain*.

Comment: <a href='h t t p ://www.something.com'>LINK</a>

Comment: @40P Please show the entire content of the email you're sending.

Comment: yep. just added it to the question description. Appreciate all the help.

Comment: @40P Looks like you have lots of nonsensical backslashes in your mail source.

Comment: That's weird because I always use single quote. Is it possible that the mail server (hosted) is not allowing links and therefore escaping stuff?

Comment: @40P What exactly are you doing with that text? First you're using `urldecode($_POST["ebody"])`, then later `$this->ebody`. Which is it?

Comment: @deceze - This saved me! I was receiving similar issues with <x-msg://7/#>  being prepended to embedded image sources when sent from Mail.app